# Build NextJS app on CI without accessing Sitecore

Tags: jss, continuous-integration

I've got a JSS application created using [Next.js Getting Started template](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html). During development, when I have local Sitecore instance runnung, I can build the app using `jss build` command. On the CI server the app is being built when the `rendering` container starts which seems too late. If there are build errors, the container will never start. See the Docker file fragment:

```
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT "npm run start:connected"
```

To prevent that, I'd like to build next.js app in advance. Ideally, on a pull request validation. But, if executed without Sitecore instance running, the `jss build` fails with connection error:

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully

> Build error occurred
FetchError: request to https://cm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
```

It even does what I need - compiles the frontend app. It just needs to be stopoed before sending the request to Sitecore. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to introduce a `CI=true` environment variable on your build server (or Azure DevOps pipeline). With it being defined only on your build server, you can adjust your application code not to call Sitecore during the build process.

In `[[...path]].tsx`, in the `getStaticPaths` function, your app is calling the Sitecore sitemap fetcher to get all the routes defined in your content tree. This is the call you can skip with that extra environment variable.

The original code looks like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  const paths = await sitemapFetcher.fetch(context);
  ...
}
```

The modified code can look like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && process.env.CI !== 'true') {
  const paths = await sitemapFetcher.fetch(context);
  ...
}
```

This will skip assembling all of your Sitecore pages with their renderings. So there might still be runtime errors. However, the rest of the code will be compiled and all of the code will be checked for type issues by the TypeScript compiler.

It seems like starting with the upcoming v21 release of Sitecore JSS, the sample application will come with a similar feature using a different environment variable:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && !process.env.DISABLE_SSG_FETCH) {
  ... 
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/commit/cc6a5878cce723db26983a727c02cc2c19448bfa

Comment: What is the downside of skipping static path collection when running in SSG?

Comment: Skipping static path collection when running in SSG will result in no pages being statically generated. All pages will be built and cached during Incremental Static Revalidation (ISR) when a first visitor will request each page. The first visit of each page might result in an HTTP 404 error while the page is being built and cached in the background.